# Extracting data from pandas based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, loops, indexing

I have a data frame `A = [1,2,3,5,9,8,11,13] and B = [2,1,6,19,16,15,14,12]`. I want to is check  is *whether the criss cross elements of the A and B are equal in any case*

For eg: here `A[0]==B[1] and B[0]==A[1]`, this is a criss cross element.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[2,1,6]})
if df.loc[0,"A"] == df.loc[1,"B"] & df.loc[1,"A"] == df.loc[0,"B"]:
    print("the values which are equal")
else:
    print("the values which are not equal")
```

Comment: You just want to check that one condition? Then why are you looping over `i` and `j`?

Comment: You're probably looking to use `loc`, for example in your code try: `if df.loc[0,"A"] == df.loc[1,"B"] and df.loc[1,"A"] == df.loc[0, "B"]:`

Comment: I want to go through all elements in the dataframe (ie across A and B)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. What other elements? Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49846461/edit) your question and specify all comparisons you want to make?

Comment: Do you want to check the diagonals of row 0 and 1, then 1 and 2 etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Compare contiguous columns

In order to check wheter or not `A[i]==B[i+1] & A[i+1]==B[i]` for all the rows in the dataframe, you can compare the colums vectorially but shifted:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,5,14,16,16,13]) # I mdified input data from the question for the second example
B = [2,1,6,19,16,15,14,12]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':A,'B':B})
eq_diag = (df['A'][:-1].values==df['B'][1:].values) & (df['A'][1:].values==df['B'][:-1].values)
# boolean array with rows=rows_in_df-1, eq_diag[i] will be true if the 
# diagonal between rows i and i+1 is equal
# Output for eq_diag
# [ True False False False False False False]
```

Then, the values which are equal in these diagonal comparisons can be printed:

```
print df[:-1][eq_diag] # the [:-1] is important for dimensions to match
# Out
    A  B
 0  1  2 # it also returns the index i (not i+1) where the diagonal is equal
```

### Compare *ALL* column combinations in the dataframe

If instead of comparing the column `i` with the column `i+1`, all possible combinations should be compared, the module `itertools` can be used:

```
import itertools
combinations =  np.array(list(itertools.combinations(range(len(df)),2)))
print combinations.T
eq_diag = ((df['A'].values[combinations[:,0]]==df['B'].values[combinations[:,1]]) & 
           (df['A'].values[combinations[:,1]]==df['B'].values[combinations[:,0]]))
# Out: all the column combinations
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 6]
 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 2 3 4 5 6 7 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 5 6 7 6 7 7]]
```

And then, the elemenst which are equal can be printed:

```
for i,j in combinations[eq_diag]:
    print 'The criss cross element of columns {} and {} is equal:\n{}'.format(i,j,df.values[[i,j]])
# Out
# The criss cross element of columns 0 and 1 is equal:
# [[1 2]
#  [2 1]]
# The criss cross element of columns 4 and 6 is equal:
# [[14 16]
#  [16 14]]
```

Comment: @Amit I updated the answer to consider also the case of all possible column combinations.